# Will an inbound iptables rule in ddwrt on port 443 break https?

Tags: networking, iptables, https

I want to run a vnc repeater service on my home ddwrt router. Due to the possibility of friends/family asking for support in unknown network environments, I'd like the host-repeater application to run on 443 (very rarely blocked), so I'm thinking I can just apply this ip tables rule.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j logaccept
```

I am concerned though, will this mess with traffic in response to outbound traffic? For example, say I connect to my bank account on https. Will the return packets I'm searching for just get directed to my router instead of my computer? I was never sure, because while it's in response to a request, it's still technically INBOUND traffic.

Additionally, I'm aware this would open me to port scans, but since I would not be running the expected protocol on 443, would I be (relatively) safe to open 443 to the rest of the world? I can't imagine someone just randomly guessing I'd be running a specific uvnc repeater AND knowing how to exploit any weakness it may have.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, outbound traffic will not be affected.

Due to most routers using Destination NAT (as opposed to Source NAT or bi-directional NAT), requests from your network are automatically given a high port number, which is then used for reverse connection mapping - see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Translation_of_the_endpoint) for more detail on NAT in general, and [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708011/how-is-source-port-for-http-determined-is-there-ever-collision-in-nat) about how the return port is calculated.

The only exceptions to this that I know of are a Linux NTP daemon (there are multiple and I can't remember which).

As for the safety aspect, port 443 is one of the most common ports scanned, and you should expect some exploitation attempts. I would advise that you put some security measures in place (basic authentication for example). I used to run my own Git server over SSH at home, and ended up receiving several hundred connection attempts per day from brute-force scanners.

Comment: Thank you, I was never clear on how this worked. Frees me up to utilize standard ports for non-standard services (with appropriate security measures).